# Collecting folly::Futures with an associated value

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I'm trying to implement a batch API where requests are associated with an id. In the batch response, the individual success/failure responses should be associated to their corresponding request id.

The code looks like this

```
class Request {};
class Response {};
class BatchResponse {};
folly::SemiFuture<Response> handle(Request foo) {
  return folly::makeSemiFuture(Response{});
}

folly::SemiFuture<BatchResponse> batchAPI() { 
  // input batched requests
  std::map<int, Request> requests = {{1, Request{}}, {2, Request{}}};

  // a collection of handled requests with their ids
  std::vector<folly::SemiFuture<std::pair<int, folly::Try<Response>>>> responses;
  responses.reserve(requests.size());

  // loop and handle requests
  for (auto& entry : requests) {
    int requestId = entry.first;
    // associate response with request id
    responses.push_back(
        handle(entry.second)
            .via(folly::getCPUExecutor().get())
            .thenTry([requestId](const folly::Try<Response>&& tryBar) {
              return std::make_pair(requestId, tryBar);
            }));
  }

  // this is the returned SemiFuture<BatchResponse>
  return folly::collectAllSemiFuture(responses)
      .via(folly::getCPUExecutor().get())
      .thenValue([](const auto& tryResponses) {
        BatchResponse response;
        for (const auto& tryPair : tryResponses) {
          // guaranteed to be successful
          std::pair<int, folly::Try<Response>> pair = tryPair.value();
          int requestId = pair.first;
          folly::Try<Response> handleResult = pair.second;

          if (handleResult.hasValue()) {
            // add value and requestId to response
          } else {
            // add exception and requestId to response
          }
        }
        return response;
      });
}
```

I don't like that I have to capture the `requestId` in the response future and transform into a `pair` of the two. As result, I have to unwrap the `std::pair` with `tryPair.value();` since I know it'll be successful.

An alternative I've considered is maintaining a parallel `std::vector` of the request ids and capturing that in the `SemiFuture` returned by `collectAllSemiFuture`, since they would be in the same order.

Are there cleaner designs?

Comment: If it can't fail, why not simply use `SemiFuture<Response>` with `.thenValue()`?

Comment: @Yuushi In which place? In the SemiFutures returned by `handle`, I need to use `thenTry` to preserve the possible exception. I do use `thenValue` for the future returned by `collectAllSemiFuture`.